# How to specify a Column for VBA's Autofilter function by name rather than by its index?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and trying to autofilter a column range. The column is named "Vlookup" and sits at index position 27.

```
rData.AutoFilter field:=27, Criteria1:="Class" ' filter criterion
```

In order to make this dynamic, I need to be able to filter according to column name rather than column index.

However, when I do

```
rData.AutoFilter field:=Application.Match("Vlookup", Selection.Rows(1), 0), Criteria1:="Class"  ' filter criterion
```

I yield

> Runtime Error '424' - Object Required

**How to correctly `Autofilter` by column name in VBA?**

Comment: You should be using `rData.Rows(1)` rather than `Selection.Rows(1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what option you went with but we had a similar issue and we discovered that it is as easy as using a table for your data then use Field:=Listobject.ListColumns("Column Name").Index. This way your solution is dynamic.

```
Set rData = Workbooks("Workbook Name").Worksheets("Sheet Name").Listobjects("Table Name")
rData.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter field:=rData.ListColumns("Vlookup").Index, Criteria1:="Class"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use helper UDF which will return column's index:

```
Function GetIndex(colName As String)
    GetIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(colName, ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Rows(1), 0)
End Function
```

**UPD**

You can substitute `ActiveSheet` with your sheet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Find` function to find "Vlookup" in the header row, and then retrieve the numeric value of the `Column`.

**Note**: there's no need to use `Selection`, instead fully qualify your `Rows(1)` with your `rData` sheet object (use the `With rData` statement).

See code and comments below:

```
Dim FindRng As Range
Dim FiltCol As Long

With rData
    Set FindRng = .Rows(1).Find(what:="Vlookup")

    If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' Find was successful
        FiltCol = FindRng.Column ' get the column number where "Vlookup" was found
    Else ' find unable to find "Vlookup"
        MsgBox "Find Error!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    .AutoFilter Field:=FiltCol, Criteria1:="Class" ' filter criterion
End With
```